# WordPress MySQL query optimization for the BuddyPress member types

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization, buddypress

I'm making one custom app that already has over 10.000.000 users.

I had to create one custom query that extracts users from a specific member type.

The problem is if I want to see only 20 users and do pagination, it needs a lot of time to get the data out of the database and often there a critical error occurs because the query is very heavy.

The same happens if I use `BP_User_Query` (Buddypress class) because my code is based on it.

The biggest problem is that Buddypress `member_type` has been recorded within WP terms and is reached via a complicated relation.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.*,
    t_ex.name AS member_type,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='first_name' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS first_name,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='last_name' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS last_name,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='nickname' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS nickname,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='description' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS description,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='last_update' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS last_update,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='wp_capabilities' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS caps,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='rich_editing' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS rich_editing
FROM
    wp_users
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_ex ON tr_ex.object_id = wp_users.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt_ex ON tt_ex.term_taxonomy_id = tr_ex.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms t_ex ON t_ex.term_id = tt_ex.term_id
WHERE
    1=1
AND
    tt_ex.taxonomy = 'bp_member_type'
AND
    t_ex.name = 'platformuser'
GROUP BY wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Is there any better solution how I can get the desired results without it being so difficult for the database.

The parameter I am looking for is located in `t_ex.name`, in my case `'platformuser'`

I think the problem is in group and order:

```
...

GROUP BY wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC

...
```

But don't know why. I need that also.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_term_relationships` -- It probably has a poor set of indexes.  (I know that wp_postmeta does.)  Also provide `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_users`, and `wp_terms` in case they need new indexes.

Comment: The WordPress schema is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for your information.

Comment: *Mirabilu dicte*, the indexes on `wp_term_relationships` are good. It's a modified many-to-many join table (with a `term_order` column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to work with.

**First** of all, ten million users is a very large number for WordPress. You already know that.

**Second**, please consider rewriting your query to do a so-called "deferred join." You have the notorious performance antipattern `SELECT many_long_rows ... ORDER BY something LIMIT small_number`.  This forces MySQL to sort a whole mess of data, just to discard all but a tiny fraction of it.

Suggested rewrite:  Start with a subquery to get the `wp_users.ID` values you're interested in.  Working from your example, the subquery is this.

```sql
         SELECT wp_users.ID
            FROM wp_users
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_ex ON tr_ex.object_id = wp_users.ID
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt_ex ON tt_ex.term_taxonomy_id = tr_ex.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_terms t_ex ON t_ex.term_id = tt_ex.term_id
           WHERE 1=1
             AND tt_ex.taxonomy = 'bp_member_type'
             AND t_ex.name = 'platformuser'
           GROUP BY wp_users.ID
           ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC
           LIMIT 0, 20
```

This has to sort a whole lot less data ... just the ID values. So it should be faster and take a whole lot less RAM in MySQL.

Then use that subquery in your main query to process the twenty users you care about.

```sql
SELECT 
    wp_users.*,
    'platformuser' AS member_type,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='first_name' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS first_name,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='last_name' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS last_name,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='nickname' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS nickname,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='description' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS description,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='last_update' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS last_update,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='wp_capabilities' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS caps,
    ( SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key='rich_editing' AND wp_usermeta.user_id=wp_users.ID ) AS rich_editing
FROM
    wp_users
WHERE wp_users.ID IN (
         SELECT wp_users.ID
            FROM wp_users
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr_ex ON tr_ex.object_id = wp_users.ID
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt_ex ON tt_ex.term_taxonomy_id = tr_ex.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_terms t_ex ON t_ex.term_id = tt_ex.term_id
           WHERE 1=1
             AND tt_ex.taxonomy = 'bp_member_type'
             AND t_ex.name = 'platformuser'
           GROUP BY wp_users.ID
           ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC
           LIMIT 0, 20
      )     
GROUP BY wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

It won't take long to look up the metadata for just twenty users.

**Third**, [WordPress's `wp_users` table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users), as defined by https://ma.tt and company, has no index on the `display_name` column. So MySQL's index trickery for avoiding a gigantic sort doesn't work. You can remediate this

- by using `ORDER BY wp_users.user_nicename` in place of `display_name`, or by
- creating an index on the `display_name` column like this.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE wp_users ADD KEY display_name (display_name);
  ```

**Fourth**, if you're running an old version of MySQL (before 8) or MariaDB (before 10.3), upgrade it. And convert your tables to use InnoDB and DYNAMIC row format. You're pushing the envelope hard with ten million users. Why use obsolete software when you do that?

**Fifth** (much less important if you do the above things) the indexes on wp_usermeta are not optimal for the kind of lookup you do. This sequence of MySQL statements will reindex the table to give you much faster lookup. This may take a while.

```
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD UNIQUE KEY umeta_id (umeta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, meta_key, umeta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP KEY user_id;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta DROP KEY meta_key;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, user_id);
```

@RickJames and I have published a (free open source) WordPress [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) to handle the InnoDB conversion and reindexing for you, or you can certainly do it yourself. You can use it with [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) to avoid timeouts.

I think the next version of our plugin should also add the `display_name` index to `wp_users` to cover your case. (I've heard of others with a similar problem.)

Answer (score 2):

What OJones says, plus

To avoid a sort:

```
       GROUP BY wp_users.ID
       ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC
```

-->

```
       GROUP BY wp_users.display_name ,    wp_users.ID
       ORDER BY wp_users.display_name ASC, wp_users.ID ASC
```

(By making those two lines essentially equal, an extra sort is prevented.)